# Theem'on Importer - don't have this option in my wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I installed the theme like the document guide, but I don't have the option for demo data importer. how can I change it? thanks
in the document:

should be

[image]

my wordpress: no option

[image]

Comment: You have to install it first, its another plugin.

Comment: I installed it. Firstly I got error of "css not found" so I unzipped the folder and Installed id manually @mx0

Comment: @mx0 I don't have the option of impoting data at all